# Бот в вк на python. Не убирается клавиатура

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, клавиатура

Хотел сделать боту клавиатуру , поигрался немного и понял , что она мне не нужна. Удалил всё связанное с клавиатурой и выключил в настройках кнопку Начать, но ничего не удалилось. Что еще надо сделать?

```
import datetime
import json
import time
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import vk_api
import _json
import random

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token="****")

vk._auth_token()

vk.get_api()
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="****")
session_api = vk_session.get_api()

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, ****)

while True:
    try:
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.object.peer_id != event.object.from_id:
                    class Late:
                        if event.object.text.lower() == "опоздаю" or event.object.text.lower() == "я опоздаю":
                            sender_name = list(filter(lambda name: name['id'] == event.obj.from_id, [name for name in
                                                                                                     session_api.messages.getConversationMembers(
                                                                                                         peer_id=event.obj.peer_id,
                                                                                                         fields='profiles')[
                                                                                                         'profiles']]))[
                                0]
                            last_and_first_name = str(sender_name['first_name']) + ' ' + str(sender_name['last_name'])
                            print(event)

                            print('-' * 30)


                    class Command:
                        if event.object.text.lower() == "помощь":
                            vk.method("messages.send",
                                      {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id, "message": "Мои команды  \n \n "
                                                                                   "1. Неделя - верхняя "
                                                                                   "или нижняя \n \n"
                                                                                   "2. Расписание по "
                                                                                   "дням: \n \n  "
                                                                                   "вторник \n "
                                                                                   "среда \n "
                                                                                   "четверг \n пятница \n "
                                                                                   " суббота", "* Все дни , кроме понедельника, дают расписание по "
                                       "random_id": 0})
                        if event.object.text.lower() == "бот":
                            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id,
                                                        "message": "Весь во внимании",
                                                        "random_id": 0, })


                    class Week:
                        if event.object.text.lower() == "неделя" or event.object.text.lower() == "какая неделя" or event.object.text.lower() == "какая неделя?":
                            if (int(time.strftime("%V")) % 2) == 0:
                                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id,
                                                            "message": "Сегодня нижняя неделя ",
                                                            "random_id": 0, })
                            else:
                                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id,
                                                            "message": "Сегодня верхняя неделя  ",
                                                            "random_id": 0})


                    class Schedule:
                        if event.object.text.lower() == "пн" or event.object.text.lower() == "понедельник":
                            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id,
                                                            "message": "К третьей паре(12:35), Литература, "
                                                                       "Математика, Химия ",
                                                            "random_id": 0})
                        if event.object.text.lower() == "вт" or event.object.text.lower() == "вторник":
                            if (int(time.strftime("%V")) % 2) == 0:
                                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id,
                                                            "message": "Химия, Физика, Информатика, Физика",
                                                            "random_id": 0})
                            else:
                                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id,
                                                            "message": "Химия, Физика, Информатика, Физика",
                                                            "random_id": 0})
                        if event.object.text.lower() == "ср" or event.object.text.lower() == "среда":
                            if (int(time.strftime("%V")) % 2) == 0:
                                vk.method("messages.send",
                                          {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id, "message": "География, Английский, Матеша",
                                           "random_id": 0})
                            else:
                                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id,
                                                            "message": "Ко второй паре(10:35), Английский, Матеша",
                                                            "random_id": 0})
                        if event.object.text.lower() == "чт" or event.object.text.lower() == "четверг":
                            if (int(time.strftime("%V")) % 2) == 0:
                                vk.method("messages.send",
                                          {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id, "message":"Ко второй паре (10:35), "
                                                                                      "География, История, Физ-ра",
                                           "random_id": 0})
                            else:
                                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id,
                                                            "message": "Ко второй паре (10:35), География, История,"
                                                                       "Физ-ра",
                                                            "random_id": 0})
                        if event.object.text.lower() == "пт" or event.object.text.lower() == "пятница":
                            if (int(time.strftime("%V")) % 2) == 0:
                                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id,
                                                            "message": "Ко второй паре(10:35), ОБЖ(?),Русский язык, "
                                                                       "Литература",
                                                            "random_id": 0})
                            else:
                                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id,
                                                            "message": "Ко второй паре(10:35), История, Русский язык, "
                                                                       "Физ-ра",
                                                            "random_id": 0})
                        if event.object.text.lower() == "сб" or event.object.text.lower() == "суббота":
                            if (int(time.strftime("%V")) % 2) == 0:
                                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id,
                                                            "message": "Ко второй паре(9:40), Модуль, ОИТ, Матеша",
                                                            "random_id": 0})
                            else:
                                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id,
                                                            "message": "Ко второй паре(9:40), Модуль , ОИТ, ОИТ",
                                                            "random_id": 0})
                        if event.object.text.lower() == "вн" or event.object.text.lower() == "воскресенье":
                            vk.method("messages.send",
                                      {"peer_id": event.object.peer_id, "message": "‍⚕️В палату, быстро!",
                                       "attachment": "photo-191492924_457239020",
                                       "random_id": 0})




                elif event.object.peer_id == event.object.from_id:
                    class ForLs:
                        if event.object.text.lower() == "привет":
                            vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id": event.object.from_id, "message": "привет",
                                                        "random_id": 0})







    except Exception as E:
        print(Exception)
```

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос.

Comment: Это весь код, не знаю . что именно  надо

Comment: Это собственно все, что надо.

Comment: ну что, как убрать?

Comment: Зачем использовать vk.method(), когда можно написать просто session_api.messages.send(user_id='пользователь')?

Comment: Да и для авторизации достаточно только этих строк -> vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="****") и сразу за ним
session_api = vk_session.get_api()

Answer (score 1):

Отправьте пустую клавиатуру

```
empty_keyboard = {'keyboard': {
    "one_time": False,
    "buttons": []
}}
 vk.method("messages.send",{"peer_id":event.object.peer_id,
                              "message":"Пустая клава",
                              "random_id":0,
                              "keyboard":empty_keyboard,
                              })
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью:

```
"keyboard":keyboard.get_empty_keyboard()
```

`keyboard` - предварительно созданная клавиатура с любыми значениями и кнопками. Хотя бы 1 кнопка, иначе выдаст ошибку.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).